# Applying for a Student Visa in Germany from Netherlands as a Non-EU citizen?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, netherlands, indian-citizens, student-visa

Can one apply for student visa in Germany from Netherlands even though I have an MVV (temporary residence permit) visa (1 year) for Netherlands and am a non-EU citizen? I am a resident of India.

If yes, how is it any different (if any) for applying for a German National Visa from one's country of residence? (Specifics would be appreciated)

(I had planned to study in Netherlands but due to financial reasons I had to look for options more financially feasible to me and having obtained such an opportunity in Germany i would like to pursue my studies there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally apply to the German representation (consulate or embassy) competent for your place of residence.

While you said you are a resident of India, if you already entered the Netherlands on a MVV, it would probably make you a resident of the Netherlands for this purpose (you would certainly need to register in the *Basisregistratie personen*). You should therefore be able to lodge your application to the German consulate general in Amsterdam if you want.

On the other hand, if you are still in India, you should apply there and the MVV would not make much of a difference. *You cannot use the MVV to enter Germany and then apply for a long-stay visa*. While a Dutch visa/permit does allow you to *visit* Germany, directly applying for a residence permit within the country is only allowed in some limited cases. As Indian citizen, you need to secure a student visa *before entering Germany* (so either in the Netherlands or in India).

Generally speaking, the process should be similar in the Netherlands and in India. One difference is that the consulate general in Amsterdam is probably smaller (not that many Dutch residents need visas for Germany) and does not use any third-party company to handle applications. You have to call the consulate directly at specific times to make an appointment ([information here](http://www.niederlande.diplo.de/Vertretung/niederlande/de/04__GK/Visabestimmungen/Visabestimmungen__seite.html), unfortunately only in Dutch or German).

As far as documentary evidence is concerned, the German consulate will probably want to see either your MVV or a proof of registration (or *uittreksel uit de BRP*) to establish that you are a resident in the Netherlands. Otherwise, the requirements should be similar.