# Applying for MVV Visa for Germany from Netherlands?

Tags: germany, netherlands, indian-citizens, student-visa

Can one apply for an MVV Visa (study) for Germany in Netherlands even though I have an MVV Visa (study) for Netherlands and am not a citizen of Netherlands?
I am a resident of India.

If yes, how is it any different (if any) for applying for an MVV visa from one's country of residence, I mean are there any particular documents one would ask for in such a case?

(I had planned to study in Netherlands but due to financial reasons I had to look for options more financially feasible to me, and having obtained such an opportunity in Germany I would like to pursue my studies there.)

Comment: Flagged for migration.

Comment: This question has been superseded by http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6492/applying-for-a-student-visa-in-germany-from-netherlands-as-a-non-eu-citizen (can't vote to close as duplicate as long as the other one has no up-voted answer apparently).