# Applying for a Sweden student visa while in UK as a student for an Indian citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, indian-citizens, passport, sweden

My question is similar to

[Applying for a Student Visa in Germany from Netherlands as a Non-EU citizen?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6492/applying-for-a-student-visa-in-germany-from-netherlands-as-a-non-eu-citizen)

I am a student in UK enrolled in a Masters program. I recently finished my Masters (September, 2018) and got an offer as a PhD student from a Swedish university. My UK Tier 4 student visa is valid up to Jan 2019. I am a citizen of India.

My question is, if it is possible for me to apply for my doctoral student visa from the Swedish embassy in London (UK) or do I need to return to India to make my application. Thanks.

Comment: The Swedish mission to the UK is the best source for this information.  Have you tried asking them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there was no answer posted to this question, I am posting my own experience.

It is absolutely possible to apply for a residence permit in Sweden from London or any other location. The Swedish migration agency (migrationsverket) does not impose any restriction on the place of application as long as you are a valid visa holder (or a residence permit holder) of that location. I have recently filed my application and received a result for the same as well.

Please bear mind this is specific to Sweden. Other countries might impose other restrictions.